# How redirect pages in JavaScript / HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am making a Google Script that use a form made in bootstrap and whem the button send is pressed the information in the form go to a Google Spreadsheet, but furthermore i need to make a redirect whem the button is pressed, how can i make it?

Google script code

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.Sandbox‌​Mode.NATIVE);
}

function setData(data) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1uU2GtTjN8SYKQduar4y4n2u0EGeQFaznRddtrmNSYN8").getSheetByName('Página1');
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    ss.getRange(lastRow+1, i+1).setValue(data[i]);
  }
  Logger.log(data[0]);
  return 0
}
```

HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getData).setData();
  });

function getData(data) {
var data = [];
    data[0] = document.getElementById("InputName").value;
    data[1] = document.getElementById("InputEmail").value;
    data[2] = document.getElementById("Inputtel").value;
    data[3] = document.getElementById("InputCPFCNPJ").value;
    data[4] = document.getElementById("InputEnterprise").value;
    data[5] = document.getElementById("InputMessage").value;
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
      if(data[i]=="" || data[i]==null){
        window.alert("Não deixe campos vazios por favor.");
        return 0;
      }
    }
    google.script.run.setData(data);
    return 0;
}
</script>

<html lang="pt-br">
    <body>
    <form role="form">

            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="InputName">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputName" placeholder="Nome">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="InputEmail">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" placeholder="e-mail">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="Inputtel">Telefone</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Inputtel" placeholder="Telefone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="InputCPFCNPJ">CPF ou CNPJ</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="InputCPFCNPJ" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="InputEnterprise">Empresa</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputEnterprise" placeholder="Empresa">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="InputMessage">Mensagem</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="InputMessage" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="getData();">
                    Enviar
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to have the user "manually" click another button to go to another page or website, if that's what you are asking.  You can use an `<a>` tag with the target blank attribute to open an new tab or page:

```
target="_blank"
```

The entire tag:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com" target="_blank">Link Text Here</a>
```

In a 'regular` website, you could use:

```
window.location
```